# Утечка памяти при скачивании файла

Tags: php, утечка-памяти

У меня возникла проблема, получаю список видео из сайта, а потом их скачиваю таким кодом:

```
file_put_contents("./videos/".rand(1,100000).".mp4",file_get_contents($url,false,stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)));
```

В итоге у меня весь код прерывается с ошибкой

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 136310784) (tried to allocate 132120608 bytes) in /root/down/start.php on line 61
```

Comment: Здесь нет никакой утечки, просто пытаться помещать весь файл в оперативку целиком — определённо плохая идея

Comment: А как сделать лучше?

Comment: Есть десяток способов скачать файл. Зачем это делать на php?

Comment: Используйте `stream_get_contents()` для чтения данных порциями и `fwrite()` для их записи в локальный файл